# Hibernate Event Listener Not Called when changes made from DB side

Tags: java, hibernate, events, listener

I am new to Hibernate. I have found out that we can have event listener in Hibernate which will notify us of changes made on DB. What I am interested in is Will the Java code be called if I am not doing any DB changes through Java application but only through DB. Here is what I have coded::

1. Hibernate CFG file and Corresponding HBM file

```
<session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url"></property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username"></property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size"></property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</property>
  <!-- Mapping files -->
  <mapping resource="hbm/ps.hbm.xml"/>

    <listener type="post-insert" class="com.Dummy"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.Bean" table="Demo">
    <id name="id" type="string" column="ID" />
    <property name="name" type="string" column="NAME"></property>
</class>
```

2. Listener Class implementing PostInsertListener::

   ```
   import org.hibernate.Session;
   import org.hibernate.event.PostInsertEvent;
   import org.hibernate.event.PostInsertEventListener;


   public class Dummy implements PostInsertEventListener
   {
        /**
        * 
        */
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       @Override
       public void onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           System.out.println(event.getEntity() instanceof Bean);
           System.out.println("Inside onPostInsert");
           Session session = event.getSession();
           System.out.println(session.toString());
       }

   }
   ```

Main Class::

```
public class Run {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
        System.out.println("Here");
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();
        SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session =     factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Bean bean= new Bean();
        bean.setId("4");
        bean.setName("Dummy");
        System.out.println("Before Insert");
        session.save(bean);
        System.out.println("After Save");
        tx.commit();
        System.out.println("After Commit");
        session.close();
        factory.close();
    }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The code works magic when i run the main class Inserts into DB as it should call the onPostInsert method as expected but if i run the application and make changes from DB ie insert a column the Console doesnt print anything. Is there something I am missing?? I am using SQL server...are there any compatibility issue with the DB??
Really messed up on this need help..... :)

Answer (score 1):

No, changes made directly on the database won't call the listener in your app.

Bulk updated / deletes emitted with hibernate won't call the listener.